# How can I make an image function as a button, and make it perform an action when clicked ( start a keyframe event, run a script)?

Tags: html, css, button

I've just started coding at school, and our teacher is horrible. I have to teach myself how to code, and for that reason, I've come here seeking help :). I've created this website using some simple html and css, and what I would like now is for the image I'm using in my navigation bar to act as a button, and when pressed, do something cool, like make an animation, or start a keyframe event where a few keyframes that I've set will trigger (like blinking text) or maybe even run a cool javascript. This is mostly for show, but at the same time, I'm here to learn. If my code is poorly written, feel free to correct it. Thank you.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="bilde.png"> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bully</title>
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stil2.css">
</center>
<center><ul class="navigation">
   <li><a href="bully2.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="" target="_blank">
         [This is that I want to use as a button ->] <img src="bilde.png" alt="Emblem" style="width:120px;height:120px;border:0";> 
        </a>
  <li><a href="orbok2.html">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="Lore.html">Lore</a></li>
</ul>


<ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item" style="font-size:42px;"><h1>~Breaking News~</h1>
  <li class="flex-item"><h1><ins>26. October, 2017.</ins></h1><br><a style="font-size:32px;">The release of the videogame "Bully 2" has just been confirmed, according to a variety of different reliable sources. Spokesperson Bad Andy from Bullworth Chess Club confirmed the release date of Bully 2 to be on January 1st of 2019. "Bully's long-awaited sequel will be a tremendous success in today's videogame-industry," said Andy in an interview with Russel Barro, owner of The Bullworth Herald.<br></a><h2>~Jimmy Hopkins~</h2></li>
  <center><ul class="flex-container">
  <center><li class="flex-item"><h1><ins>18. October, 2017.</ins></h1><br><a style="font-size:32px;">Fire alarm was set off at 11:24 by unknown student or person. Faculty and staff encourage all students to send in clues and tips about the incident to: Bullworthacademy@edu.com</a><br><h2>~Staff~</h2></li>
  <center><ul class="flex-container">
  <center><li class="flex-item"><h1><ins>Bully 2 "confirmed" by R* insider?</ins></h1><br><a style="font-size:32px;">Trusted gtaforum.com-admin "Yan2295" made a post on April 21st saying this: <br> <br> </a>
  <img src="yan.png" style="border:2.5px solid black;width:65%;height:250px;">
  </p><br><h2>~Russel Hustle~</h2></li>
</div>
</ul>

</body>
</html>


CSS
@import "compass/css3";

/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
body{
  background-image:url("brun.jpeg");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:1270px;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}

.flex-container {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width:1000px;
  list-style: none;
  flex-direction:column;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-flow: row-wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  margin-left:0;
  border-top:0px solid ;
  border-left:3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-bottom:0px solid ;
  border-right:3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-radius:0px;
  padding-bottom:100px;
  padding-top:100px;

  line-height:40px;
  color:rgba(252, 174, 26, 255);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family:NarcissusOpenSG;
  text-align:center;
  flex-grow: 0;
  justify-content:space-around;
  animation-name:text;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-duration:2s;
  animation-direction:alternate;
}
@keyframes jtext{

from {
  color:rgba(252, 174, 26, 255);
}
to{
    color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
}
.navigation {
  list-style: none;
  border-top:3px solid black;
  border-bottom:0px solid black;
  width:994px;
  border-right:3px solid black;
  border-left:3px solid black;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  text-align:center; 
  align-items:center;
  padding:0;
  border-top-left-radius:50px;
  border-top-right-radius:50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content:space-around;
  font-family:NarcissusOpenSG;
  font-size:28px;
}

.navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding:0;
  padding: 1em;
  opacity:0.5;
  transition-duration:0.5s;
  color:rgba(252, 174, 26, 255);
}

.navigation a:hover {
  color;
  background:;
  opacity:1;
  animation-duration:1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-name:blink;
  animation-direction:alternate;
}
keyframes blink {

from {
opacity:0.75;
  }

to {
opacity:0;
}
}
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
  .navigation {
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navigation {
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
  }

  .navigation a { 
    text-align: center; 
    padding:10px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3); 
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
  }


  .navigation li:last-of-type a {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: center is deprecated. Run your html through a validator - it is not valid

Comment: Hi :) I would recommend that you first get some more experience with the basics before you post your questions here.
If you have difficulties I can offer you a 101 in HTML/CSS and Javascript/jQuery. Your Tags are also a bit false, as jQuery Tag is present in the tag but not in your code (not even the library).

Comment: remove `</center>` and all `<center>`.  Move the stylesheet link to the head tag. Add a `<div>` after the `<body>` and style that to center. Move the `</div>` to the other side of the `</ul>`

Comment: I've removed all center tags, and I've cleaned up the code as suggested. I tried styling the div to center, but I'm not getting any results.

Answer (score 2):

There are ways of doing this:

1. Add an anchor tag like this

   `<a type="button" href="the url" id="myId">put the image element here</a>`
2. Write a click function in javascript for the element with an id

   `document.getElementById("myId").onclick=function() { /* some code here */ }`

Answer (score 0):

You can add image button with below tag inside button

```
<input type="image" src="http://somesite.com/somepath/someimage.png" />
```

or

```
<button style="background: url(someimage.png)" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

If your image is of a proper size, you can set it as a background for that particular "a" tag.

So it should be something like this:

```
<li><a  class="funImage" href="" target="_blank"></a></li>
```

And then in your css you could do something like this:

```
.funImage{display: inline-block;
          background-image: url("bilde.png");
          height: /*Set height accordingly*/;
          width: /*Set width accordingly*/; 
         }
```

Hope that works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with Jquery.

```
<img src="yan.png" alt="image" id="image">
```

And in your script put this code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#image').click(function(){ 
        alert('image clicked');
      });
    });
</script>
```

In seated of an alert you can do something cool.